# How to get the access_token in Django-all auth with GitHub social account?

Tags: django, github, django-allauth

I am working on a project and successfully set up the django-allauth using GitHub social account in an app named 'auth'. Now, I need profile details and access to a particular repository of authenticated users in another app, and for that, I need an access token but I am facing errors with that.

How to do it? Any suggestion on this?

Below is the code I am using to fetch access token:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .utils import get_github_profile_details, get_repo_details

@login_required
def profile(request):
    social_account = request.user.socialaccount_set.first()
    if not social_account:
        messages.error(request, 'No social account found. Please log in with GitHub.')
        return redirect('account_login')

    social_token = social_account.socialtoken_set.first()
    if not social_token:
        messages.error(request, 'No access token found. Please log in with GitHub.')
        return redirect('account_login')

    access_token = social_token.token
    profile = get_github_profile_details(access_token)
    repo_name = f"ProgrammersPost-{profile['username']}"
    repo_details = get_repo_details(access_token, repo_name)

    context = {
        'profile': profile,
        'repo_details': repo_details,
    }

    return render(request, 'proprofile/profile.html', context)
```

I need to get the access token.